# Error in implicit statement: Parameter ‘a’ has not been declared

Tags: fortran, double, precision, implicit

I am working on a old Fortran code. Until this morning  I was able to compile it. But today,I did not change anything, it says

```
impli.for:1:33:

       IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H,O-Z)
                                 1
Error: Parameter ‘a’ at (1) has not been declared or is a variable, which does not reduce to a constant expression
```

Do you know  how can I fix it? It's a old code and I don't want to change so many things.

I compile using gfortran.

Comment: You have to show us your code. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Almost certainly you have changed *something*. If you can't show us the code, compare it to your backups.

Comment: I find it strange that the error is supposed to be in the first line of the file as said in the compiler error. How could your code stop compiling on its own without any change to the code?

Comment: Maybe it's an INCLUDE file.